# MediaPlayer doesn't loop in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've tried to play asset sound with MediaPlayer.

```
MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(); 
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(path); 
m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() ); 
descriptor.close(); 
m.prepare();
m.setLooping(bLoop); 
m.start();
```

It works well on old Android versions, but not on Android 6.0.
If you have experience and have an answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this.

```
     m.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            m.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: When the MediaPlayer should be removed, memory leak will be occurred.

Comment: I am not sure why don't repeat MediaPlayer.
I've fixed problem with this code.

Answer (score 0):

if user `setLooping`

after `start`, help?

or mb u can help `MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer.create();`

Comment: Yes, after start, the sound is playing one time, not repeated.

Comment: @TalentedMobileDeveloper the MediaPlayer objects created using new is in the Idle state, while those created with one of the overloaded convenient create methods are NOT in the Idle state. In fact, the objects are in the Prepared state if the creation using create method is successful.

Comment: Most important is current code works well on old Android devices, not Android 6.0.
It doesn't work only on Android 6.0.